# Полоса стамины через ColorRect (C# GODOT)

Tags: c#, godot

У меня есть шейдер:

```
shader_type canvas_item;
render_mode unshaded;
uniform vec4 green_color : source_color = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.85);
uniform vec4 red_color : source_color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.85);
uniform float perehod : hint_range(0.0, 200.0) = 0.0;
void fragment()
{
    vec4 color = mix(red_color, green_color, perehod / 200.0);
    COLOR = (color - (UV.x - perehod / 200.0)) * 0.6;
}
```

У меня есть глобальная переменная, как мне и где мне задать переменной perehod  значение переменной (глобальной) из скрипта?

Comment: Если прям совсем-совсем глобальная, то [global uniform](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shaders/shader_reference/shading_language.html#global-uniforms) наверное?

Comment: @andreymal можете пояснить? Когда я пишу public перед uniform, выдает ошибку, а когда пишу перед uniform global, пишет: https://imgur.com/a/ptzfujH